# Protractor - Failed: Error while running testForAngular: A script did not complete before its timeout expired

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium-webdriver, safari, protractor

I cannot get past these failures while using Protractor to run end-to-end regression tests against an Angular application. When I run the same tests against Chrome and Firefox, both ALWAYS pass. However, when running against either Safari or Safari Technology Preview...I get the same stack failure. This IS a Angular App so I cannot just "turn off" or "disable" waiting for Angular.

Node 8.0.0, Protractor 5.1.1, npm 5.0.4, Selenium 3.4.0.jar, macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Safari - 10.1.1 (12603.2.4)

Safari Technology Preview - Release 35 (Safari 11.0, WebKit 12604.1.29)

*Allow remote automation enabled

Safari Stack:

```
NoSuchWindowError: A request to use a window could not be satisfied because the window could not be found.

Failed: Error while running testForAngular: A script did not complete before its timeout expired.
```

Safari Technology Preview Stack:

```
Failed: Error while running testForAngular: A script did not complete before its timeout expired.

Command duration or timeout: 20.01 seconds

Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.5', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, version=12604.1.29, cleanSession=true, platform=MAC, nativeEvents=true,
locationContextEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=safari, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=macOS, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
```

Protractor Config file

```
"use strict";

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    capabilities: {
    browserName: 'safari',
    'safari.options': {technologyPreview: true },
    }

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 500000,
    includeStackTrace : true
    },
    onPrepare: functionI() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1200);
    },
    getPageTimeout: 500000,

    allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    specs:['10ALMWspec.js', '11ALMWspec.js']
};
```

JavaScript spec file

```
"use strict";

var loginPage = require('../pages/mobileWebLoginPage.js');
var homePage = require('../pages/mobileWebHomePage.js');

describe('10ALMWspec', function() {
    it('Should validate login and logout functionality', function() {
        loginPage.getDEV();
        loginPage.mobileWebValidLogin();
        expect(homePage.contactName.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        expect(homePage.clickToSelectTeamAnchor.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        expect(homePage.logOutBtn.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        homePage.logOutBtn.click(); 
    });
});
```

JavaScript page file

```
'use strict';

var MobileWebLoginPage = function()
{
    this.testUserLoginInputBox = element(by.css('[data-qa-id="loginALMWUserIdInput"]'));
    this.testUserPasswordInputBox = element(by.css('[data-qa-id="passwordALMWInput"]'));
    this.loginBtn = element(by.css('[data-qa-id="loginALMWBtn"]'));
    this.popUpMessage = element(by.css('[class="popup-body"] span'));
    this.popUpMessageOkBtn = element(by.css('[class="popup-buttons"] button'));

    this.getDEV = function()
    {
      browser.get('https://foo/mobile-app/', 500000);
    };
    this.getUAT = function()
    {
      browser.get('https://bar/mobile-app/', 500000);
    };
    this.mobileWebValidLogin = function()
    {
      this.testUserLoginInputBox.sendKeys('testuser');
      this.testUserPasswordInputBox.sendKeys('testpassword');
      this.loginBtn.click();
    };
    this.mobileWebInvalidLogin = function()
    {
      this.testUserLoginInputBox.sendKeys('testuser2');
      this.testUserPasswordInputBox.sendKeys('test2password');
      this.loginBtn.click();
    };
};

module.exports = new MobileWebLoginPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the root of you issue is not an Angular waiting functionality. It is appear because there is an error `NoSuchWindowError: A request to use a window could not be satisfied because the window could not be found.`.
Take a look at [issue on the SeleniumHQ github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3796)

Comment: Oleksii, I've already looked at the page you linked to. Which is why, after reading all of the comments on that page, I installed STP and tried running my tests on BOTH Safari and Safari Technology Preview. The solution they provide claims to work, but I can confirm (see my STP stack trace above) that it clearly does not work. The window resizing IS fixed, but my tests will not run. The correct page renders at the correct URL, but the WebDriver cannot drive the browser. No commands are executed after the page renders.

Comment: Why you can't turn off Angular wait? You could add your own expected condition.

Comment: Because it's an Angular application. All the pages are in Angular. You cannot turn off Angular wait on an Angular application. "If you need to navigate to a page which does not use Angular, you can turn off waiting for Angular". [link] https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md

Comment: Do you Angular app can not be tested using Java or Python? :) Angular waiting it is just nice help feature, nothing more. I understand that it is not root of your issue, but turn on you brain at first). Sorry, that I can not help you.